# Use method within another method in a Javascript Class - currently getting undefined

Tags: javascript, class

Just trying to learn ES6 classes and trying to figure out this problem I am having. I have a method named `claim` where I need to use another method to calculate the probability of something which is called `probability` which both take two arguments. I am getting `probability is not defined. What am I doing wrong using classes? Do I need to define it in the constructor?

Error Message

```
ReferenceError: probability is not defined
```

Code

```
class Game {
  constructor(players) {
    this._players =  this.createPlayers(players);
    this._total_dice = this.totalDice(players);
  }

  move (id, dice, value) {
    var current_player = this._players[id - 1];
    this._players[id - 1] = { id: current_player.id, dice_middle: dice, value: value, dice_left: current_player.dice_left - dice };
    this._total_dice = this._total_dice - dice;

    console.log([this._total_dice, this._players[id - 1]])
  }

  claim (dice, value) {
    var result = (probability(this._total_dice, this._total_dice) + probability(this._total_dice - 1.0, this._total_dice)) * 100
    console.log(result);
  }

  factorial(n) {
    if (n < 0) { return -1; } else if (n == 0) { return 1; }
    var number = n;
    while (number-- > 2) { number *= n; } return number;
  }

  probability(n, k) {
    if (k <= n) {
      return (this.factorial(n) / (this.factorial(k) * this.factorial(n - k))) * Math.pow(1.0/6.0, k) * Math.pow(5.0/6.0, n-k);
    } else {
      return 0.0;
    }
  }

  createPlayers(amount) {
    var players = [];
    var player_count = new Array(amount).join().split(',').map(function(item, index){ return ++index; })

    for ( var i = 0; i < player_count.length; i++) {
      var player = { id: i + 1, dice_middle: 0, value: 0, dice_left: 5 }
      players.push(player);
    }

    return players;
  }

  totalDice(amount) {
    var total = amount * 5;
    return total;
  }  
}

var game = new Game(4);
game.move(1, 2, 3);
game.move(1, 1, 3);
game.claim(2,3);
```

You'll see that probability is also using a factorial method to calculate the factorial of the arguments. I am assuming whatever the issue is, I can apply a fix to both so both the claim method and probability method can be resolved or at least defined. Note that I have the move method working correctly but it doesn't need any other method to work.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), very likely duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `probability` is an instance method on `class Game`, you need to reference it by using `this.`, the same way as you have done for your other methods:

```
claim (dice, value) {
    var result = (this.probability(this._total_dice, this._total_dice) + this.probability(this._total_dice - 1.0, this._total_dice)) * 100
                  ^^^                                                    ^^^
    console.log(result);
}
```

As written, your code is looking for a method called `probability` further up the scope.

Comment: Thanks! - i did have this originally but when I run the file, it doesn't print my console log or anything in `claim` - guess something must be wrong with my factorial or probability methods.

Comment: Yep, it was my stupid factorial method that was broken. Thanks though for the help!